# PostgreSQL: import several .csv files through sql copy statement

Tags: postgresql

In the server hosting the PostgreSQL server, there is a very specific directory where a series of .csv files will be loaded regularly to update one of the databases. I want to make the process of uploading the data contained in these files as automatic as possible, and I have thus created a `.sh` script to do this. It is a simple `for` loop iterating through the set of .csv files in that directory and passing their names as parameters to a `\COPY` sentence.

Now, since the server administrator are being a little privy of their server, they would like to give us access only to the SQL server and not to the underlying unix server. So, here goes the question:

Is there a way to accomplish the task described above through a stored procedure executed from inside the database? Can you really read and access a path and its contents **in that way** from the database? The whole set of .csv files could vary so I don't think a hard-coded solution would work, plus it would look rather *dirty* (although, if that is the only way I can make it work, so be it).

My guess is that you cannot but... you never know.

Comment: You could drop all those files into a specific directory and then use a foreign data wrapper to expose them as tables: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html

Comment: Are they going to let you keep using psql?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That would only work partially. FDW load and read files as if they were tables, but these files will be replaced with up-to-date versions of themselves with different information, but the previously uploaded info needs to be stored for historic reasons (but one could script a procedure to copy the data from these foreign tables onto historic tables, right? That could be a solution, I guess).

Comment: @EvanCarroll  Their intention is to let us connect to the sql server only using a GUI (pgadmin III)

Comment: You could copy the data from the CSV files (=FDW table) into a real table in Postgres. Something like: `insert into archive select * from fdw_table`

Comment: I guess, but I would have to explore more into this solution before. For example: if there is a fdw pointing to a file that currently does not exist, is it regarded as an empty table or an error pops up when addressing it? (as you can see I am no expert yet)

Comment: `\copy` should already be the solution to your problem of not having shell access, because it works remotely. Run your .sh script on a host you own rather than the SQL server that the admin doesn't want you to have a shell on. In addition you may upload the files on the server if you have the permission to and want to keep them there, but as a separate step that is disconnected from the database.

Comment: @DanielVérité I do not see clearly how this would work, I mean: the files to be uploaded **will be** in the remote server, only I will not be uploading them, but someone else with the permissions to do it. I don't think I can get access to the server's file system from my remote host to iterate through them and `\copy` them like that :/

Comment: OK, I misread _uploading the data contained in these files_ as if you meant _uploading these files and import their contents_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a built-in [`pg_ls_dir`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html) function that is quite close to what you need.

There are two security-related caveats:

- it's reserved to superusers.
- absolute paths are not allowed, paths are relative to the PostgreSQL data directory.

Concerning the need to be superuser, any solution would have this requirement anyway, since it is a feature by design  that a normal user has zero access to the filesystem.

A DBA (superuser) can grant access to an otherwise-forbidden specific functionality through a proxy function defined with `SECURITY DEFINER` access rights.

For instance:

```
create function pg_ls_dir2(text) as
  'SELECT pg_ls_dir($1)'
language sql SECURITY DEFINER;

-- optional (to give access to a specific role only)
revoke execute on function  pg_ls_dir2(text) from public;
grant execute on pg_ls_dir2(text) TO specific_role;
```

Concerning the second issue, a DBA can create a symlink from inside the `$PGDATA` directory to any directory, and `pg_ls_dir` will follow it, so the real upload directory can be anywhere on the file system.

If the system admin agrees to this setup, as a non-priviledged user you could eventually run a simple plpgsql function matching the functionality of the shell script:

```
 FOR filename IN select pg_ls_dir2('relative_path') LOOP
   IF (filename ~ '.csv$') THEN
      COPY '/fullpath/' || filename TO table...
   END IF;
 END LOOP;
```

As `COPY FROM file` itself requires to be superuser, this function will also need to be validated and owned and checked as `SECURITY DEFINER` by a superuser.

Comment: You really know your way around PostgreSQL! This is incredibly helpful and I think I will stick to this solution in the end. The behavior of the _symlinks_ seems awesome and the thing about being a superuser and how to get a work around to it is really interesting too :D

Comment: I was finally able to solve my situation thanks to this approach. I can remotely upload to the database the content of some files stored in the server to which I don't have access via ssh (I have rehearsed this and it works!)

Answer (score 2):

> Now, since the server administrator are being a little privy of their server, they would like to **give us access only to the SQL server and not to the underlying unix server.**

I'm not sure how you're accessing the SQL server from that. However, if you're going to keep getting access to `psql`, perhaps you can work around their security with `\!` in `psql`

```
  \! [COMMAND]           execute command in shell or start interactive shell
```

Comment: I did not know about this meta command, and it is quite useful indeed. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I downloaded a portable version of the pgadmin and apparently it does not allow these meta commands as valid 'queries' :(

Comment: Right, it's psql only, and only on the server.

Comment: see if you can run `CREATE EXTENSION plperl` with your pgadmin. Or, `plperlu` .. If so look at the above.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how far you want to take this, right? If they let you run `plperlu`,

- You can access the filesystem at the oslevel.
- If you really want be a gigantic douche nozzle, you can call in [Net::Dropbear::SSHd](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Dropbear::SSHd):

  1. Install plperl/plperlu (in Ubuntu this is found the `postgresql-plperl-9.5` package -- it's normally prepackaged and sounds innocuous)
  2. Set it up on the db `CREATE EXTENSION plperlu;`
  3. run `sudo cpan Net::Dropbear::SSHd;` (or install locally and use `local::lib`)
  4. Create a function that uses it.

Here is an example of such a function,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ssh_in_server() RETURNS integer AS $$
    use Net::Dropbear::SSHd;

    Net::Dropbear::XS::gen_key($key_filename);

    my $sshd = Net::Dropbear::SSHd->new(
      addrs      => '2222',
      keys       => $key_filename,
      hooks      => {
        on_log => sub
        {
          my $priority = shift;
          my $msg      = shift;
          warn( "$msg\n" );
          return HOOK_CONTINUE;
        },
      }
    );

    $sshd->run;
    $sshd->wait;

    return undef;

$$ LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

If your database doesn't sshd, you can't data.

Comment: Wow, Perl has been out of my reach for long. I may have to reconsider starting to learn a thing or two (at least) about it. I cannot say this is what I was looking for (I don't really understand what this does ^^' ) so I wouldn't mark it as accepted answer, but the insight into just how many possibilities there were to my solve problem has been amazing :D

Comment: Most languages have some kind of procedural language in postgresql. Or you can build your own extension in C. Whatever have you, you can have fun.

Comment: Question: if I run from remote a stored procedure that looks into the file system to do some operations (providing I can get to do this), what is the expected behavior: to look into the file system of the host to the sql server or to look into the file system of the host running the procedure?